# UWP XAML Popup not respecting VerticalAlignment?

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to center a Popup in a Windows Store/UWP app.

In brief, I'm taking MainPage and adding...

- A `TextBlock` with some text
- A `Button` with an event handler, `Button_Click`
- A `Popup` named `popupTest`. It contains...

  - A `Border` with...

    - A `StackPanel` with

      - A `TextBlock`
      - A `Button`. This `Button`'s event handle sets the `Popup`'s `IsOpen` to false.

`Button_Click` calls `_centerPopup`, which tries to center the `Popup` and then sets `IsOpen` to `true`. I can't get this to work.

```
private void _centerPopup(Popup popup, Border popupBorder, FrameworkElement extraElement = null)
{
    double ratio = .9; // How much of the window the popup fills, give or take. (90%)

    Panel pnl = (Panel)popup.Parent;
    double parentHeight = pnl.ActualHeight;
    double parentWidth = pnl.ActualWidth;

    // Min 200 for each dimension.
    double width = parentWidth * ratio > 200 ? parentWidth * ratio : 200;
    double height = parentHeight * ratio > 200 ? parentHeight * ratio : 200;

    popup.Width = width;
    popup.Height = height;

    //popup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;    // <<< This is ignored?!

    // Resize the border too. Not sure how to get this "for free".
    popupBorder.Width = width;
    popupBorder.Height = height;

    // Not using this here, but if there's anything else that needs resizing, do it.
    if (null != extraElement)
    {
        extraElement.Width = width;
        extraElement.Height = height;
    }
}
```

If I don't try to resize and center the Popup in Button_Click, here's what I get after clicking "Click Me"...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //_centerPopup(this.popupTest, this.popupTestBorder);
    this.popupTest.IsOpen = true;
}
```

[image: Click Me clicked, no resizing or centering]

If I uncomment out the call to _`centerPopup`, I get this, with the popup staying *under* the button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _centerPopup(this.popupTest, this.popupTestBorder);
    this.popupTest.IsOpen = true;
}
```

[image: with recentering and resizing]

That's no good. I [thought](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) `popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;` would've fixed that.

> FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment Property
>
> Gets or sets the vertical alignment characteristics applied to this element when it is composed within a parent element such as a panel or items control.

---

#### Move Popup to top of StackPanel?

Strangely, if I move the Popup up to the top of my StackPanel, it actually pushes the other controls down after being shown.

Clicking "Click Me" *without* `_centerPopup`:

[image: looks promising]

That looks promising! It's floating over the other controls nicely, and there's no obvious impact to the layout after it's closed.

But add back `_centerPopup`, even after commenting out setting `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`, and things die a horrible, fiery death.

[image: Pushes controls down]

It looks perfect ***until you notice that every other control was pushed down***. ??? Here's *after* clicking "Click to close":

[image: stuff is pushed down permanently]

Other controls are pushed down *permanently*. Why does that happen? Shouldn't the popup float like it did before I resized it?

---

### Full Source

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="PopupPlay.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PopupPlay"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Name="StackMain">
        <TextBlock>
            This is some text<LineBreak />
            This is some text<LineBreak />
            This is some text<LineBreak />
            This is some text<LineBreak />
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click Me"></Button>

        <Popup x:Name="popupTest">
            <Border
                    Name="popupTestBorder"
                    Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="2">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Name="txtPopup"
                               Text="This is some text"
                               FontSize="24"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Name="btnClose"
                            Click="btnClose_Click"
                               Content="Click to close"></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**Full MainPage.xaml.cs code**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

namespace PopupPlay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _centerPopup(this.popupTest, this.popupTestBorder);

            this.popupTest.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void _centerPopup(Popup popup, Border popupBorder, FrameworkElement extraElement = null)
        {
            double ratio = .9; // How much of the window the popup fills, give or take. (90%)
    
            Panel pnl = (Panel)popup.Parent;
            double parentHeight = pnl.ActualHeight;
            double parentWidth = pnl.ActualWidth;
    
            // Min 200 for each dimension.
            double width = parentWidth * ratio > 200 ? parentWidth * ratio : 200;
            double height = parentHeight * ratio > 200 ? parentHeight * ratio : 200;
    
            popup.Width = width;
            popup.Height = height;
    
            //popup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;    // <<< This is ignored?!
    
            // Resize the border too. Not sure how to get this "for free".
            popupBorder.Width = width;
            popupBorder.Height = height;
    
            // Not using this here, but if there's anything else that needs resizing, do it.
            if (null != extraElement)
            {
                extraElement.Width = width;
                extraElement.Height = height;
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupTest.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

There are several questions that seem related. I do not see a viable fix. (Note: These are not all UWP specific.)

- [Center Popup in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906170/center-popup-in-xaml)
- [Place Popup at top right corner of a window in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220262/place-popup-at-top-right-corner-of-a-window-in-xaml)
- [How to set vertical offset for popup having variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286017/how-to-set-vertical-offset-for-popup-having-variable-height)

Painfully, this same setup is working for me in another app when it's positioned in a much more complicated grid with a Pivot, but I see that [pivots are buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701190/popup-not-showing).

Wpf's `Placement` stuff [sounds promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170230/popup-control-verticalalignment-doesnt-catch), but doesn't exist in UWP-land.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Popup` is inside a vertical `StackPanel`, which means the `StackPanel` will lay out the popup alongside the other child elements of the panel, which is why it pushes down the text.

Also, the `VerticalAlignment` is being ignored by the panel because the panel allocated exactly enough vertical space for the popup's size, and so there is no room for it to align the popup vertically within the space it was allocated.

I would suggest using a `Grid` as the root element for the `Page`, and putting the `StackPanel` and `Popup` directly inside the `Grid`, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="StackMain">
        <TextBlock>
        This is some text<LineBreak />
        This is some text<LineBreak />
        This is some text<LineBreak />
        This is some text<LineBreak />
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click Me"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup x:Name="popupTest">
        <Border
                Name="popupTestBorder"
                Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
                BorderThickness="2">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Name="txtPopup"
                           Text="This is some text"
                           FontSize="24"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button Name="btnClose"
                        Click="btnClose_Click"
                           Content="Click to close"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

`Grid`s are good for this purpose, when you want to have overlapping elements or multiple elements that do not affect the position and size of any other child element. You want the layout of the popup to be *separate* from the layout of the stack panel and its children, so you should organize your XAML as such.

Comment: Okay, I think that helps rethread my head a little. I'd tried a Grid before, but put the Popup into its own row, which had some of the same trouble, both on `Height="Auto"` and `Height="0"`. I thought the Popup was designed to flyover the *parent Panel* (Grid or StackPanel), but what you're showing is that it's designed to fly over *its row in the Panel*, so to speak. That is, if your wrapping Grid here had two rows, the Popup would only flyover one (pick your choice). Not super intuitive imo, but you've got it down cold here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your xaml as follows...

```
<Page...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Popup>
        </Popup>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

So move the Popup control outside the content area and put your stacklayout with all content inside the ContentPanel Grid ( as shown in code sample above )

That should stop pushing the other controls down...

Comment: This answer is right, and before DecadeMoon's, but Moon's answer really made it come into focus for me why the StackPanel wasn't working (you can't exactly share rows in a StackPanel, so to speak), so I'm +1ing here and giving the check there. Sorry I can't split the check, and thanks a lot!